# get gridview control inside loginview asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, loginview

I am working with loginview. There is a gridview inside loginview and I want to Bind it with databse table, but I couldn't access this gridview inside .cs code.

I tried this:

```
GridView GridView1 = (GridView)LoginView1.FindControl("GridView1");
```

but gridview again hasn't initialized. 
Note that in a web.config file I set

```
<authentication mode="Forms"/>
```

Does someone know the solution of this problem?

The part of code this:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    <asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">  
     <LoggedInTemplate>  

      <div class="tab-content" id="mytabcontent">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="new1">
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
            </asp:GridView>   
        </div>
        </div>
      </LoggedInTemplate>  

      <AnonymousTemplate>  
               <asp:HyperLink runat="server" navigationURL =         "default.aspx">Login</asp:HyperLink>
       </AnonymousTemplate>  
     </asp:LoginView> 

</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be getting this error as the user might not be authenticated.

Try

```
 if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
 {
     GridView GridView1 = (GridView)LoginView1.FindControl("GridView1");

 }
```

Use Breakpoint and Check whether the the line to access Gridview is called.

UPdate:

To authenticate create a Auth Cookie

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new
                              FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, //version
                              username.ToString(),                    //user name
                              DateTime.Now,                //creation
                              DateTime.Now.AddDays(365), //Expiration
                              false, ""
                    //Persistent
                              );

                System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username.ToString(), true);
```

// Redirect to Secured page after creating  a cookie in login page

Comment: yes, the compilation error has disappeared now. but even I have authorized I see Hypelink,i.e. control for AnonymousTemplate. Why?

Comment: How can you say you are authorized. In the page load use this bool IsAuthenticated = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated and check whether you are really authenticated or not. I dont know how you are authenticated the user. By using the code you can make sure

Comment: IsAuthenticated is false. I am using following code to authorize:      e.Authenticated = true;
Session["userID"] = Login1.UserName;
Response.Redirect("admin.aspx");

Comment: It means you are not authenticated

Comment: TO authorize you need to create some AuthTicket only then you can authenticate. I dont think what you are doing is correct

Answer (score 0):

You could just handle the init event of the GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnInit="GridView1_Init">
</asp:GridView>
```